# How can I do matching images with streaming live camera

Tags: python

I am working on small project the next step requires matching equation and how can I convert it to python code.

So, How can I do comparison between stored pictures with streaming live camera; using python.

Waiting your response.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question to clarify your problem. If possible add some code and error messages. For guidance please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many libraries to do this, i personally suggest OpenCV or SimpleCV it will work for you